# 3 mothers each having 1 child; no mother should be interviewed before the child. How many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Three ladies have brought one child each for admission to a school. the principal wants to interview the six people one by one subject to the condition that no mother is interviewed before her child. Then find the number of ways in which the interviewers can be arranged.

Can someone help me solve this question?

Comment: How many ways can you arrange $aabbcc$?  In whichever arrangement of $aabbcc$, capitalize the right-most occurrence of each letter.  Relate this to your current problem.  [Multinomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) should be helpful here.

Comment: @JMoravitz got it...thank you. Post this as an answer

Comment: @JMoravitz $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ counts all arrangement of $aabbcc$, but how it ensures the constraint, I can't model this, please help.

Comment: @mathlover "*capitalize the right-most occurrence of each letter.  Relate this to your current problem.*"  So... the lower case letter $a$ will represent the child of mother $A$, and the upper case $A$ represents the mother $A$.  Since we capitalize the right-most occurrence of each letter, capital letter will be before its paired lowercase letter...